# Concentration (or two sided tail bounds around expectations) of maximum and minimum of $n$ iid, subgaussian random variables

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, random-matrices, random-walks

I asked this on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3663396/concentration-or-two-sided-tail-bounds-around-expectations-of-maximum-and-mini), but got no answer, hence asking here now. Help appreciated!

My question is motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460412/concentration-of-maximum-of-gaussians/1460650?noredirect=1#comment7502121_1460650) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460412/concentration-of-maximum-of-gaussians/1460650?noredirect=1#comment7502121_1460650), where the first was aimed for giving a one sided tail bound for maximum of subgaussians, and the second one was for two sided tail bounds for gaussians. I'm also motivated by questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961780/prove-that-the-maximum-of-n-independent-standard-normal-random-variables-is-a?rq=1).

Let $\{X_1 \dots X_n\}$ be $n$ iid, subgaussian random variables so that $P[|X_i| \ge t] \le 2 exp (- \frac{ct^2}{ ||X_1||_{\psi_2}^2 }) \forall i, ||*||_{\psi_2}$ denoting the Orlicz norm. I'm looking for concentration inequalities for :

$$  X_{max} := max_{1 \le i \le n} X_i, \hspace{1mm}    X_{min} := min_{1 \le i \le n} X_i   $$

So to be more precise, I'm looking for tail bound functions $\alpha(t), \beta(t)$ of the form:

$$ P[  | X_{max} - \mathbb{E}X_{max} | \ge t ] \le  \alpha(t), P[  | X_{min} - \mathbb{E}X_{min} | \ge t ] \le  \beta(t)  $$

where the following are decreasing functions of $t$:

$$ 0 \le \alpha(t), \beta(t) \to 0, t \to \infty.$$

*Out of curiosity, I've been asking myself: why do I keep seeing various results on tail probabilities of **only maximum** of a set of random variables, but **not minimum** of them?*

Comment: If you don't take absolute values, the max and min of symmetric random variables (such as Gaussians) have the same distribution, up to sign.

Comment: Regarding concentration of the max of Gaussians: See Theorem 5.2.2 in Vershynin's High Dimensional Probability book. Maximum is a Lipschitz function.

Comment: I think the sub-gaussianity condition by itself is inadequate for the bounds you want. Indeed, this condition implies upper bounds on the tails of $X_{\max}$ and hence on $EX_{\max}$, but leaves the difference $X_{\max}-EX_{\max}$ without proper control.

Comment: @IosifPinelis thanks for your comment! I think I still need to do some thinking to convince myself, but the reason I was thinking of such a two-sided tail estimate was I was hoping for as we increase $n, X_{max}$ should move further away from $0,$ and since each $X_i$ has a tail probability estimate around $EX_i,$ I was hoping there has to be some kind of "pivot" around which $X_{max}$ should concentrate, and I was hoping this "pivot" should be $EX_{max},$ but from what you wrote, we can't control $|X_{max} - EX_{max}|.$ I was hoping for a lower bound on $EX_{max}$ too (contd.)

Comment: @IosifPinelis (contd.) ...as intuitively, with large $n, EX_{max}$ should be far from $EX_1 $($X_i'$ s are iid). But then I wonder: is $X_{max}$ even a subgaussian? I guess I'll do some calculation of the tail estimate to get something like $P[ | X_{max} |   \ge t]  \le  g(t),$ though I'd be more happy with something like $P[ | X_{max} -c |   \ge t]  \le  g(t)...$ (but maybe it's impossible...)

Comment: @AryehKontorovich Thanks for the pointer to the theorem in Vershynin's book: yes max is a Lipschitz function, with the Lipschitz constant depending on $n,$ the number of $X_i$'s considered (or the dimension). But the theorem should still apply - I'll do the necessary calculation.

Comment: @IosifPinelis My mistake -- I misread the OP as "gaussian" rather than "subgaussian".